# SQL Server 2016: can't reference JSON array path using JSON_MODIFY

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have tried for a few hours to get my issue working, but I am unsuccessful.

I pass a complex JSON object to a stored procedure and after I insert the main record, I then get that new record ID, and use it to change a couple other ID's within the JSON object.

I am successful using JSON_MODIFY like this.. when the value is not within an array.

```
SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.Weather.RoundID', @round_identity)
```

but when the value is within an array, I can't seem to get it to work.

This works when I hardcode the index of the path:

```
SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.Scores[0].RoundID', @round_identity);
```

This doesn't work:

```
SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.Scores['+ STR(@Score_Counter) + '].RoundID', @round_identity);
```

The error is:

> The argument 2 of the "JSON_MODIFY" must be a string literal

The value `@Score_Counter` is generated by a while loop to index the current array object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Bill

Update:
With the help of Bogdan, I was able to successfully change the json in the arrays.
Here is what I am using:

```
--Loop and populate all scores to set RoundID using Dynamic SQL
Set @Score_Counter = 0;
Set @Score_Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OPENJSON(@json, N'lax $.Scores'))

WHILE @Score_Counter < @Score_Count
BEGIN
    SELECT  @SqlStatement = CONCAT(N'SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY    (@json, ''$.Scores[', @Score_Counter, N'].RoundID'', ' + cast(@round_identity as nvarchar(10))+')')
    EXEC    sp_executesql @SqlStatement, N'@json NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @json = @json OUTPUT
    SET @Score_Counter = @Score_Counter + 1;
END;
```

Comment: Loops are anathema to SQL. Any way you can use `OPENJSON` or `JSON_QUERY` in combination with `WHERE` to get the objects to update as rows, then `JSON_MODIFY` it without referring to an array index? You could shred rows into a temporary table first, and build the result back with `FOR JSON`. If all else fails you could, of course, build the whole `JSON_MODIFY` expression with dynamic SQL, but that should be a last resort (and doesn't play nice with variables in an outer scope, regardless).

Comment: I tried the Dynamic SQL route, and still had issues (namely the scope issues). I am baffled that passing in a simple index value can bring the JSON_MODIFY function to its knees.

Comment: Awesome man, Your **Update** code work seamlessly for me. You should add that as an answer.